# Javascript flatten deep nested children

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, while-loop, nested-loops

I really can't figure out this one. I'm trying to flatten the `category_id` that are deep child of a specific node.

```
var categories = [{
  "category_id": "66",
  "parent_id": "59"
}, {
  "category_id": "68",
  "parent_id": "67",
}, {
  "category_id": "69",
  "parent_id": "59"
}, {
  "category_id": "59",
  "parent_id": "0",
}, {
  "category_id": "67",
  "parent_id": "66"
}, {
  "category_id": "69",
  "parent_id": "59"
}];
```

Or visually:

[image]

The closest I got to was to recursively loop through the first item found:

```
function children(category) {
    var children = [];
    var getChild = function(curr_id) {
        // how can I handle all of the cats, and not only the first one?
        return _.first(_.filter(categories, {
            'parent_id': String(curr_id)
        }));
    };

    var curr = category.category_id;

    while (getChild(curr)) {
        var child = getChild(curr).category_id;
        children.push(child);
        curr = child;
    }

    return children;
}
```

Current output of `children(59)` is `['66', '67', '68']`.

Expected output is `['66', '67', '68', '69']`

Comment: Why does anything need to be recursive? This is a simple array of objects.

Comment: Because there are multiple levels, my parent_id is always the closest parent, unless I am overseeing something?

Comment: so you want all the children id's starting from a parent including all nodes below that parent?

Comment: This is pretty close to a topological sort, in case you're googling later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test but it should work:

```
function getChildren(id, categories) {
  var children = [];
  _.filter(categories, function(c) {
    return c["parent_id"] === id;
  }).forEach(function(c) {
    children.push(c);
    children = children.concat(getChildren(c.category_id, categories));
  })

  return children;
}
```

I am using lodash.

Edit: I tested it and now it should work. See the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/pmENXRl0yoNnTczfbEnT?p=preview

Here is a small optimisation you can make by discarding the filtered categories.

```
function getChildren(id, categories) {
  var children = [];
  var notMatching = [];
  _.filter(categories, function(c) {
    if(c["parent_id"] === id)
      return true;
    else
      notMatching.push(c);
  }).forEach(function(c) {
    children.push(c);
    children = children.concat(getChildren(c.category_id, notMatching));
  })

  return children;
}
```